# Roslyn - Remove reference from session

Tags: plugins, roslyn

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way , my understanding of Roslyn is very basic. 
How can I remove a referenced dll from a session in Roslyn? Is there a way?

I am trying to replace the referenced dll with a new version.

Thanks

Comment: Why do that? I suspect you refer to a Scripting Session which is the abstraction over the script you want to execute, not a model of the code. Why change the script instead of creating it the way you want it in the first place? Are you trying to "reuse" an existing session instead of creating a new one?

Comment: what if I need to keep the current session and update to a newer version of the reference (ie this is why I wanted to remove the reference)

Comment: That's a different script, therefore a different session. BTW, with the current version over 18 months old, the final version of Roslyn may be completely different in this respect